# web3py encode method call parameters

Tags: web3js, web3.py, encoding

I want to encode the parameters needed to call a contract method. 
In web3js I would use `web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(types, values);`
I need to do the same in python I found a function called `encodeABI()` which takes arguments: `fn_name, args=None, kwargs=None, data=None`
Unfortunately the documentation for this method is missing. So my question is how to encode these parameters using web3py?

Comment: The arguments you describe seem straightforward. What did you try, and where did you run into trouble?

Comment: I did not try this yet, because there is no documentation for this method I would like to know what stays for `args, kwargs` and why I need to specify the function name when in web3js it's not needed

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [eth-abi](https://eth-abi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/encoding.html#encoding-python-values) library.

```
>>> from eth_abi import encode_abi
>>> encode_abi(['bytes32', 'bytes32'], [b'a', b'b']) 
b'a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

In eth-abi v4 the syntax is simply:

```
from eth_abi import encode
encode(['bytes32', 'bytes32'], [b'a', b'b'])
>>> from eth_abi import encode_abi
>>> encode_abi(['bytes32', 'bytes32'], [b'a', b'b']) 
b'a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you should do:

```python
my_contract.encodeABI (fn_name='my_method', args=[arg1, arg2, ...])
```

This is similar to Web3js:

```js
myContract.methods.myMethod.encodeABI (arg1, arg2, ...)
```

See details in [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/d5d55e90fc2e1b2b719375cf99c397a5ce2f9752/docs/contracts.rst).

Answer (score 1):

Use **contract.selector**

Example:

For get contract use this code:

```
def getInfo(abi, address):
    api = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)
    return api

def contractFunction(address, param1, param2):
    abi = """
            json abi code   
          """
    return getInfo(abi, address).functions.contractFunction(param1, param2)
```

And when you make sign transactions, in data you may use this code:

```
'data': str(contractFunction(contract, param1, param2).selector)
  + param1.rjust(64, '0')
  + param2.rjust(64, '0')
```

There contract is first 4 symbols of hash contract function with parameter, and other symbols is symbols, appended to 64 symbols with 0

Answer (score 0):

I needed to encode web3.py contract constructor arguments to verify contract programmatically on Etherscan.

Was really missing the JS `web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters()` function and the closest alternative to it really seems to be as @kclowes says eth-abi library. I also found that `contract.encodeABI(fn_name='my_method', args=[])` doesn't work for constructors. 4 years later and still no functions in web3.py itself.
In the end, after hours of research & trial and error, this worked for me:

```
import eth_abi
import json

...

def GetEncodedConstructorArgs(functionArgs):
  abiJSON = json.loads(contractAbiAsString)
  constructorABI = None
  for item in abiJSON:
    #if item['name'] == 'MyFunction': # if you need to find function by name
    if item['type'] == 'constructor': # if you need to find constructor, as it has no name
      constructorABI = item
  argumentTypes = []
  for functionArgument in constructorABI['inputs']:
    argumentTypes.append(functionArgument['type'])
  argumentValues = list(functionArgs.values())
  encodedArgs = eth_abi.abi.encode(argumentTypes, argumentValues).hex()
  return encodedArgs
```

Declare constructor/function parameters & use them

```
functionArgs = {
  'name': 'Token Name',
  'symbol': 'TTSMBL',
}

encodedArgs = GetEncodedConstructorArgs(functionArgs)
```

And if you want to avoid supplying `functionArgs` again for the actual function call, then instead of doing this:

```
contract.functions.MyFunction(name='Token Name', symbol='TTSMBL')
```

You can simply unpack them:

```
contract.functions.MyFunction(**functionArgs)
```