# How to send bytes data to contract with web3.py to decode

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, bytes, decoding

I'm doing a test and trying to send bytes data to a contract so it can parse, store in variables, and return a value.

Solidity code

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;


contract testbyte {

    function sendBytes(bytes calldata _data) external pure returns (address) {
        (uint amountIn, uint amountOut, address pool) = abi.decode(_data, (uint, uint, address));

        return pool;


    }
}
```

I was looking at this answer here but passing the bytes data was done in Javascript.
[Parsing solidity bytes to params](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/111491/parsing-solidity-bytes-to-params)

Python code

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(node_provider))

# I collect all data, abi, etc in between.

data = {
    'amountIn': 1, 
    'amountOut': 2,
    'pool': 'pool address here'
}

# I usually do w3.toBytes(text='') to pass nothing on mainnet contracts.
bytes_data = w3.toBytes(text=str(data))

pool = contract.functions.sendBytes(bytes_data).call()
print(pool)
```

I get the bytes output

```
b"{'amountIn': 1, 'amountOut': 2, 'pool': 'pool address here'}"
```

If I try to pass that the contract reverts and if I try via remix I get

```
transact to testbyte.sendBytes errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="{'amountIn': 1, 'amountOut': 2, 'pool': 'pool address here'}", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.5.0)
```

From researching I can only guess that my byte input is incorrect, or something in my contract is wrong, but I'm unsure.

### **UPDATE 1:**

After looking at example in comment I ended up here: [web3py encode method call parameters](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/65037/web3py-encode-method-call-parameters)

I tried using the second method but I get contract reverted.

```
test_encode = encode_abi(['uint', 'uint', 'address'], [1, 2, '0xAD5ce863aE3E4E9394Ab43d4ba0D80f419F61789'])

contract.functions.sendBytes(test_encode).call()
```

When I try the first method mixed with the second

```
contract.encodeABI(fn_name='sendBytes', args=[test_encode])
```

It returns

```
0x4c93893a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000ad5ce863ae3e4e9394ab43d4ba0d80f419f61789
```

Randomly I input that into remix it return values, but all wrong values.

So I am still confused, the js portion seemed easier.
[Recovering data from Bytes using Assembly](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119342/recovering-data-from-bytes-using-assembly/119519)

### UPDATE 2:

This code works when I take the output and input it into remix

```
test_encode = encode_abi(['uint', 'uint', 'address'], [1, 2, '0xAD5ce863aE3E4E9394Ab43d4ba0D80f419F61789'],)

contract.encodeABI(fn_name='sendBytes', args=[test_encode], data=test_encode)
```

output:

```
0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000ad5ce863ae3e4e9394ab43d4ba0d80f419f617890000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000ad5ce863ae3e4e9394ab43d4ba0d80f419f61789
```

When entered into remix it returns the right values! But now I don't know how to pass the data in a web3.py call. I keep getting execution reverted.

Comment: The input data is encoded as json. Search for a json decoder in solidity. I'd recommend to change how the input data is encoded. Decoding a json string in solidity will be expensive since it is string manipulation. If possible I'd recommend to use a struct as input data that way the compiler will generate the decoder.

Comment: @Ismael When you say change input data do you mean the data I'm sending to the function or the bytes parameter itself? I'd prefer to send input via bytes. I can send an array like `[1,2,pool]` but I'm not sure how I would send a struct via web3 py to the contract to decode.

Comment: If you want to send byte see the example in the answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119342/recovering-data-from-bytes-using-assembly/119519

Comment: @Ismael Updated post. I looked into this but it's in JavaScript. I am still having trouble passing the bytes data. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @Ismael went down a rabbit hole after your link and I got it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It seems that my contract address was wrong in my .env file (whoops). After I corrected that I used the code below.

```
from eth_abi import encode_abi

test_encode = encode_abi(['uint', 'uint', 'address'], [1, 2, '0xAD5ce863aE3E4E9394Ab43d4ba0D80f419F61789'],) # Basically map the types to the values

pool = contract.functions.sendBytes(test_encode).call()
print(pool)
```

outputs

```
['0xAD5ce863aE3E4E9394Ab43d4ba0D80f419F61789']
```

If you want to use arrays you can do

```
test_encode = encode_abi(['uint[]', 'uint[]', 'address'], [[1,2], [3,4], '0xAD5ce863aE3E4E9394Ab43d4ba0D80f419F61789'],)
```

I could not use

```
contract.encodeABI(fn_name='sendBytes', args=[test_encode], data=test_encode)
```

I believe I was using it wrong, and the data it outputs is a string. When you input the value into remix it works. I can only assume remix handles things differently. Maybe someone can explain how to use this properly in the comments.